# Preloading a UIImageView animation using objective c for the iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I have an animated image which works great. It consists of 180 high quality images and it plays fine and loops continuously. My problem is that the first time I load the view containing these images it takes a long time to load. Every subsequent time after that it loads immediately as I am assuming that the images have been cached or preloaded!!! I come from a flash background and as I am sure you aware preloaders are as common as muck so I don't feel this should be difficult to find but after countless googling I cannot find any good examples on preloading or any articles on why there is a delay and what to do about it.

So my question(s) is this:

1. Is there a checkbox in the info.plist to preload all my images at the start of the app?
2. How can you preload images and are there any simple example projects that I could look at?
3. Is this the best way to implement what is essentially a video but has been output to a png sequence?
4. Is there another method as viewDidLoad does not work as I expect it to do. It traces "FINISHED LOADING IMAGES" (see code below) but the view does not show for a second or two after the images have been loaded so if the view does not show until the images have loaded then neither will the UIActivityIndicatorView which is also in the same view.
5. How do you do event listening in objective c?

**Below is the code in the viewDidLoad which I believe is fairly standard:**

Any help is greatly appreciated as I am banging my head on a brick wall on something that seems so basic in ui development. Help :)

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    imageArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:IMAGE_COUNT];

    NSLog(@"START LOADING IMAGES");

    // Build array of images, cycling through image names
    for (int i = 0; i < IMAGE_COUNT; i++){
        [imageArray addObject:[UIImage imageNamed: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Main_%d.png", i]]];
    }

    animatedImages = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,20,IMAGE_WIDTH, IMAGE_HEIGHT)];
    animatedImages.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithArray:imageArray];
    animatedImages.animationDuration = 6.0;
    animatedImages.animationRepeatCount = 0;    
    [self.view addSubview:animatedImages];
    animatedImages.startAnimating;
    [animatedImages release];

    NSLog(@"FINISH LOADING IMAGES");

}
```

Cheers

M

Answer (score 7):

In case someone finds this question, I have an answer, which is to pre-render the images like this.

```
NSMutableArray *menuanimationImages = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (int aniCount = 1; aniCount < 21; aniCount++) {
    NSString *fileLocation = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: [NSString stringWithFormat: @"bg%i", aniCount + 1] ofType: @"png"];

    // here is the code to load and pre-render the image
    UIImage *frameImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile: fileLocation];
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(frameImage.size);
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, frameImage.size.width, frameImage.size.height);
    [frameImage drawInRect:rect];
    UIImage *renderedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    // then add the resulting image to the array
    [menuanimationImages addObject:renderedImage];
}

settingsBackground.animationImages = menuanimationImages;
```

I have tried multiple other methods of pre-loading images, and this is the only thing I've found that works.

Comment: I received a memory warning with this method.

Comment: Yes, we are forcing all the images into memory. If they are too big to fit, then I don't see a way to get the performance you need. At least see if there is anything else you can release before running this code.

Comment: Nope, there is nothing else in my view. My images are quite high res and there are 270 of them though. Maybe I could look into the gaming libraries to see if that could help?

Answer (score 0):

```
My problem is that the first time I load the view containing these images it takes a long time to load. Every subsequent time after that it loads immediately as I am assuming that the images have been cached or preloaded
```

you are right at this point ...... as you are using method `imageNamed`: for this method document quotes.....

```
This method looks in the system caches for an image object with the specified name and returns that object if it exists. If a matching image object is not already in the cache, this method loads the image data from the specified file, caches it, and then returns the resulting object.
```

so in my opinion, rather than doing following stuff in viewDidLoad, you should do it earlier where delay is of not considerable......

```
    for (int i = 0; i < IMAGE_COUNT; i++)
    { 
    [imageArray addObject:[UIImage imageNamed: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Main_%d.png", i]]]; 
}
```

**another approach**

```
- (void)spinLayer:(CALayer *)inLayer duration:(CFTimeInterval)inDuration
        direction:(int)direction
{
    CABasicAnimation* rotationAnimation;

    // Rotate about the z axis
    rotationAnimation = 
    [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"];

    // Rotate 360 degress, in direction specified
    rotationAnimation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat: M_PI * 2.0 * direction];

    // Perform the rotation over this many seconds
    rotationAnimation.duration = inDuration;
    rotationAnimation.repeatCount = 100;
    //rotationAnimation.

    // Set the pacing of the animation
    //rotationAnimation.timingFunction = 
    [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];

    // Add animation to the layer and make it so
    [inLayer addAnimation:rotationAnimation forKey:@"rotationAnimation"];
}
```

this method will help in animation call it as follow(I am assuming that you are putting above method in same class where you have `imageView`.

```
[self spinLayer:yourImageView.layer duration:5.0
            direction:<-1 or 1 for anti clockwise or clockwise spin>];
```

remember just set only one image to that `imageView`(which you wish to animate.
thanks,

Comment: Like where? What method should I do this in and how can I tell when it has loaded? Is there a way to preload all these images into the cache at the beginning of the project :)

Comment: One option is appDelegate's  method ..... But this will result in startup delay....
Another option is to run that code in backgrotnd for first time.....

Comment: I've decided to start with  apreloader view and then load another view with all the images in but not show it or display it off screen so that all the images are cached, then show the application. How can I detect in the controller when the new view has loaded. i.e. an event listener of sorts to indicate viewDidLoad occurred.

Comment: Here we do not have any controllable condition when we will be able to know that images are loaded(we don't have any particular notion of event, so we can not listen it) , but we have viewWillApear(it might be useful)....... but it has delay.

Comment: So if i'm loading say 1000 images is there no way to accurately tell when they are loaded and ready to use? What is the delay on viewWillAppear?

Comment: It will be called when all the nibs/resources are loaded and viewDidLoad has completed... the call for viewWillApear varies... generally its 1-2 second but it may vary.

Comment: Thanks Ravin for your help. It seems a bit bizarre that objective-c cannot be that accurate when most programming languages are accurate to within milliseconds. The more I deal with objective-c the more it seems to quirky to be reliable. is it like that or am I just not understanding the language and its environment as a lot of things I take for granted seem to be illusive... :)

Comment: @Michael, as you are using images for animation, is that animation is in y or x axis? and are the images have only the phase difference? then there is another approach for doing this and reducing overhead of loading so many images.

Comment: Hey Ravin, Basically I abuilt this microsote in flash and I am trying to recreate it as an ipad application. http://www.animal.co.uk/watches/

Comment: It is just a 2d (video) animation I take it you meant does it change on the z axis which it doesn't. What is the better technique :) Cheers

Comment: I have updated above answer with code.( this approach is using core animation it will be better if it generated desired outcome).