# How can I get my segues to transition more smoothly?

Tags: ios, multithreading, ios5, segue

In my prepare for segue method I'm setting a couple of properties in the view controller that I'm segueing to:

```
    ShowPlantTVC *showPlant = [segue destinationViewController];
    [showPlant setInfoForTable:self.vegTableInfo]; 
    [showPlant setTitle:self.vegTableInfo.VegetableName];
```

In my viewDidLoad method in the destinationconroller I'm setting a bunch of UI properties to be display once it's being segued to. One of the properties is an image. The problem is that this imag is being printed on the screen as the segue is taking place and it's making the segue real jumpy and not smooth. when I try to segue without displaying the image it's fine. I thought about somehow using a queue and grand central dispatch but when I tried it the image wasn't displaying at all. I'm not at all familiar with grand central dispatch so I might be doing something wrong. Heres the the image that I'm displaying in the table view being segued to:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    self.showPlantImage.image  = self.infoForTable.VegetableImage;
}
```

How can I make improve the segue transition?

Comment: If your not worried about blocking the UI while the image draws, you can just move the code to ViewDidAppear: so it won't fire until after the segue and the view is already done transitioning. Otherwise load it in the background.

Answer (score 1):

You need to preload the image, so it's immediately ready for display. There's some sample code for that here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10137375/434004