# Preloading a UIImageView with CABasicAnimation

Tags: objective-c, animation, optimization, uiimageview, cabasicanimation

I'm working on an app in which i use quite animations. I found that to optimize `spritesheet` we could preload animations, and it works very well. Here is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5632007/preloading-a-uiimageview-animation-using-objective-c-for-the-iphone/10137375#10137375).

But i was asking, if this sort of optimization could also works with `CABasicAnimations` like this :

```
CABasicAnimation * myAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.translation.x"];
myAnimation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0f]
myAnimation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:200.0f];
myAnimation.duration = t;
myAnimation.repeatCount = 1;
[myUIImageView.layer addAnimation:myAnimation forKey:@"myAnimation"];
```

Because it works with `UIImageView`, even if it's based on a `CABasicAnimation`.

So, is it possible to preload my `CABasicAnimation`with this sort of process ?
And if not, how to ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Use a `CAKeyframeAnimation`. Set its `calculationMode` to `kCAAnimationDiscrete`. Set its `values` to an `NSArray` of `NSNumber` objects, one for each animation frame's x offset in your sprite sheet.

Comment: It will preload the animations, so reduce lags in execution ? So how to "translate" my example of animation in `CAKeyframeAnimation` ?